# Heroku deployment error: No runtime requirements

Tags: php, heroku, server, composer-php, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy a PHP app on heroku but I get the following error:

```
remote: 
remote: -----> PHP app detected
remote: -----> Bootstrapping...
remote: -----> Installing platform packages...
remote:        NOTICE: No runtime required in composer.json; requirements
remote:        from dependencies in composer.lock will be used for selection
remote:        - php (7.0.9)
remote:        - apache (2.4.20)
remote:        - nginx (1.8.1)
remote: -----> Installing dependencies...
```

Apparently only the css is not working, which I find weird since I use the w3.css framework and I am including it via the CDN.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is not showing an error, it's telling you to pick a runtime. If you can access it at all, it picked one for you.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am sorry. I do not understand what you're saying. I'm new to heroku. What is a runtime and how do I pick one? And how is the runtime related with the css not displaying correctly?

Comment: Something to run php. In your case, it is one of `php (7.0.9)` *or* `apache (2.4.20)` *or* `nginx (1.8.1)`. The last two are both webservers, and you don't need two of those.

Answer (score 2):

So, I solved this `Runtime` warning by adding
`require: ^7.0.0` in the composer.json.

Kudos to @ElliottFrisch for the hints.